# Hide AlertDialog when click on List item

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have created an alert dialog with `TextView` and a List with options. The user can select one item from the list or add a new one with the `EditText`.

The problem is that the `alertDialog` is only hidden when I give the button to add new and not when I click on an item in the list.

```
final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    final LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    final View dialogGroup = inflater.inflate(R.layout.select_group_layout, null);
    final EditText newGroup = dialogGroup.findViewById(R.id.new_group);
    final ListView listView = dialogGroup.findViewById(R.id.groups_list);


    listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list));
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
            HelperTools.showInfo("Selected group: " + ((TextView) view).getText(), getClass());
        }
    });

    builder.setView(dialogGroup)
            .setTitle(R.string.departments_txt)
            .setPositiveButton("Añadir", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    contactDepartment = newGroup.getText().toString();
                    HelperTools.showInfo("Selected group: " + contactDepartment, getClass());
                }
            });

    if (list.size() != 0) {
        builder.create();
        builder.show();
    }
```

How can I hide the AlertDialog when they pick a ListView item?

Thanks.

**EDIT**

Final code:

```
    final AlertDialog builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
    final LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    final View dialogGroup = inflater.inflate(R.layout.select_group_layout, null);
    final EditText newGroup = dialogGroup.findViewById(R.id.new_group);
    final ListView listView = dialogGroup.findViewById(R.id.groups_list);


    listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list));
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
            HelperTools.showInfo("Selected group: " + ((TextView) view).getText(), getClass());
            builder.dismiss();
        }
    });

    builder.setView(dialogGroup);
    builder.setTitle(R.string.departments_txt);
    builder.setButton(Dialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Añadir", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            contactDepartment = newGroup.getText().toString();
            HelperTools.showInfo("Selected group: " + contactDepartment, getClass());
        }
    });

    if (list.size() != 0) {
        builder.show();
    }
```

Comment: add "dismiss()" into your onClick listener for an item selected. That should dismiss the dialog.

Comment: That does not work. I tried that and builder.hide() but nothing works

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add  builder.dismiss(); after clicking item in listview.

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                            int position, long id) {
        HelperTools.showInfo("Selected group: " + ((TextView) view).getText(), getClass());
        builder.dismiss();
    }
});
```

**EDIT**:

Create AlterDialog like this

```
final AlertDialog builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
```

To show dialog

```
builder.show();
```

To cancel dialog

```
builder.dismiss();
```

Comment: Cannot find symbol method dismiss()

Comment: Don't use alertDialog.builder..Instead create dialog and use it.

Comment: That works but how can I add setTitle and setPositiveButton?

Comment: builder.setTitle()..You wil get every method from the dialog..Even you can set your own view also..create() dialog once initially itself..

Comment: Solved. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you can use **Dialog.dismiss()**

> **[dismiss()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html)**
>   Dismiss this dialog, removing it from the screen.

```
 AlertDialog dialog=builder.create();
                            //then put dialog.dismiss() to 
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                            int position, long id) {
        HelperTools.showInfo("Selected group: " + ((TextView) view).getText(), getClass());
        if (dialog.isShowing()){
            dialog.dismiss();
        }

    }
});
```

Comment: Cannot find symbol method dismiss()

Comment: What is 'ans'? Android Studio?

Comment: @JacinMontava 
 
ans means i have updated my answer check it

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this Code:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                            int position, long id) {
        HelperTools.showInfo("Selected group: " + ((TextView) view).getText(), getClass());


    }
});
```

use this code :

```
builder.setSingleChoiceItems(list, position, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int position)
            {
                // do something
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
```

Comment: Incompatible types: Builder cannot be converted to AlertDialog